# How should I set the text position?

Tags: html, css

http://oi62.tinypic.com/33lo87l.jpg

[image]

The navigation and banner both are in a single file. 'banner.php'

I want to position the "Login Successfully" text just besides the navigation!

I tried margin-top:0px; but still its displaying after the contents of banner.php

My CSS:

```
#container{
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:800px;
    height:auto;
}

#content_container{
    background-color:red;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:155px;
}

body {
    background-image:url(thebackground.png);
    width:100%;
}
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
<?php include 'banner.php'; ?>
<div id="content_container">
<h1>Login Successful <?php echo $_SESSION['username']?></h1>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS Code of Banner.php:

```
<style>


#nav 
{
margin-left:auto;
width:800px;
}

a:link {text-decoration:none;}
a:visited {text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
a:active {text-decoration:none;}
#tbl1
{
font-family: Calibri;
border-collapse:collapse;
border:1px solid #b9ccdc;
}
#tbl1 td
{
font-size:15px;
border:1px solid #b9ccdc;
}
#tbl1 th
{

font-size:17px;
height:32px;
width:150px;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#6298c2, #82b2d8); 
color:#f7fbff;
}

tr:hover
{
background: #deeaf4;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Show the contents of `banner.php`

Comment: Use [`float:left`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) for the menu and give it `width`. Otherwise, the `div` is set to `display: block`, which renders its width to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

If banner is div (list) or any block element you should use float:

```
#nav{
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

#content_container {
  width: 600px;
  float: left;
}
```

and then clear using some clearfix method. In additon you set width of #nav to 800px. It shouldn't rather take the whole screen.Possible clearfix methods are presented here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: Nopes..its appearing exactly below navigation table. I want it besides navigation...at the right side.

Comment: Remove also margin-left for your #nav . You should also read more about how float works, for example http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Ohkk! now I am getting like this :
http://oi57.tinypic.com/2rdxp3b.jpg
now how should i bring it down?? besides navigation??

Comment: Sorry, but it seems your layout is not very good. You should read more about floats because we won't code the whole site for you